# Update notification - reuse already existing intent data

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

Whenever a new app is installed, I show a notification like following:

```
public static void showNotification(Context context, String appPackageName) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewAppFoundActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra("appPackageName", appPackageName);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        String appName = AppUtil.getAppName(appPackageName);
        if (appName == null) {
            appName = appPackageName;
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NotificationChannelManager.CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_not)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.icon))
                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.new_app_found_title))
                .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.new_app_found_notification_info))
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText(context.getString(R.string.new_app_found_notification_info_long, appName)))
                .setColor(Color.parseColor("#25baa2"))
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

                .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(BaseDef.NOT_ID_NEW_APP, builder.build());
    }
```

My problem is, I want to change this to support multiple installs while notification is shown. So I have following question:

How can I get the intent from a shown notification of which I know the id? Pseudo code looks like following:

```
// !!! PSEUDO CODE !!!
Intent intent = null;
if (isNotificationWithIdShown(BaseDef.NOT_ID_NEW_APP)) {
    intent  = getNotificationIntent(BaseDef.NOT_ID_NEW_APP);
    // reuse this intent and add new apps instead of creating a new intent with a single app
} else {
    intent = new Intent(context, NewAppFoundActivity.class);
    // add first app to intent
}
```

Any ideas how to achieve this? I want to avoid having to save the data in a database/preferencesas this would be redundant, but this would be my alternative solution...

Comment: So you want to show a new notification when a new app is installed?

Comment: Somehow correct, I show the same notification again (I reuse the same id), so this will automatically update the current notification

Comment: I don't understand your needs. You want to show a new notification when a new app is installed or reuse the same for a new installed app?

Comment: I want to reuse it. But reusing in android is done by creating a new notification, sending it to androids notification service with the same id as any previous notifications and android will handle this as an update. That's just how it works, at least the only way I know of.

Comment: My needs are simple, getting a displayed notifications intent, by only knowing the notification id

Comment: You just answered to your own question. Doesn't matter if you create a new intent. Use the same id to update.

Comment: I need the old intent data (in my example, I need the extra called `appPackageName`) and then I can add the additional extra to the intent.